# Liferay: changing locales for a site programmatically

Tags: liferay, locale

Is there a way to change the status of site´s locales programatically?

I have to make a script that implies changing locales for some sites of our portal. In other words, having an object Group, I´d like to change the locales in its settings.

https://i.stack.imgur.com/Xypas.png

Note we are using Liferay Portal 6.2.

Thanks in advance.

EDIT for clarifying: I´m executing the script through Control Panel -> Server admin -> Script. Here is where I have the problem commented:

```
//customAvailableLocales is a String containing the locales the site should have associated
    Locale[] languageArray = LanguageUtil.getAvailableLocales(groupId);
    if(languageArray != null && languageArray .length > 0){
        for(int i = 0;i<languageArray.length;i++) {
           if(!customAvailableLocales.contains(languageArray [i].toString())){
            //Here, the locale should be disassociated to the site (from current col. to available col.)

           }
    }
}
```

Getting into the TypeSettings to change the locales there, I have this:

```
//group is where I´d like to change locales
    UnicodeProperties uniprops = group.getTypeSettingsProperties();
    uniprops.setProperty("locales",customAvailableLocales);
    group.setTypeSettingsProperties(uniprops);
```

But the group has not the same locales in the "current" column and in the TypeSetting, as I can see in the settings through the Control Panel.

Comment: Please be more specific: What kind of "script"? What have you tried so far?

Comment: Hey, thanks for replying :) Particularly, is a script in groovy, but can be of any type really. At this point, I have tried to manipulate the field TypeSettingsProperties (the UnicodeProperties associated to each group), but it always has, in the "locales" property, two locales: english and spanish, but in the column "current" there are three locales: english, spanish and euskera.

Comment: Welcome to stackoverflow. We always try to improve questions by [editing](/posts/33802520/edit) until every user understands them without reading all the comments. Could you explain, in what kind of context you are executing your script. I had expected a browser first - but apparently you are trying to use some API like REST, Webservice, Remote EJBs? As every API is different, you will need to be more specifc. A short snippet of your current code would help as well.

Comment: Thank you for the advise. I´ve done some editting. Let me know if there were more problems of understanding :-)

Comment: Have you solved your issue? I have the same problem:)

Comment: Sadly, no :-(

I´m giving it another try this morning, but can´t spend so much time with it. Anyway, I´m starting to think there is something wrong with our portal because the only field I found that has info about locales is in the TypeSettings property of the group but is useless due to always having contradictory information :S

Comment: By the way, try this yourself and see what comes within. You could have better luck than me --> UnicodeProperties uniprops = group.getTypeSettingsProperties();

Comment: Check my answer below

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I find the solution for you (for us). Add to your code

```
UnicodeProperties uniprops = group.getTypeSettingsProperties();
uniprops.setProperty("inheritLocales", "false"); // add this line
uniprops.setProperty("locales",customAvailableLocales);    
group.setTypeSettingsProperties(uniprops);
GroupLocalServiceUtil.updateGroup(group) // and this will update your group/site
```

It works fine to me!

Comment: It´s alive! Thank you very much, pal, it works!. That "inheritLocales" was the key :)