# Liferay 6.2: How to set default site language programatically?

Tags: liferay, liferay-6

I want to change default language on my site programmatically (like how I can go to `site settings -> display settings` and set available and default locales).

[image: Change default language]

So how I can do it with liferay build-in functionality?

Comment: Could you please explain, what you mean with _programmatically_ and _build-in functionality_? Do you mean from a portlet, using the API?

Comment: I solved my problem here :) http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33802520/liferay-changing-locales-for-a-site-programmatically/33867455#33867455